# Register and Run a background task from another background task

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

My app is suspended and not on the screen; it runs only once, I register my first background task (TimeTrigger based) and then restart my phone to make sure my app is completely suspended. I don’t run the app again.

I have two background tasks:

1)  First Background task triggered by TimeTrigger (15 minutes intervals)

2)  Second background task triggered by DeviceUseTrigger

Now, when after 15 minutes interval, my first background task starts and try to register my second background task at that time I get "The system has denied the background task request".

So I got this impression that DeviceUseTrigger background task cannot be registered and run from WITHIN any other background task, it always needs a UI thread. (Am I correct here? Please let me know).

I have another question, can I use Push Notification to run the background task with DeviceUseTrigger?

Can Push Notification act as UI thread to register and run DeviceUseTrigger and somehow I don’t get the error when I call 
await _deviceUseTrigger.RequestAsync(deviceId);

Comment: Need code. You can use Task and pass in a TaskScheduler object to set which context you want things to run in. But we can't do much without code.

Comment: Background task register must in UI thread. From notification you can launch your app, after app launched,of course you can register a background task.